# Problems with uploading Excel files in NetSuite

Tags: javascript, excel, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am working on designing a custom page in NetSuite to facilitate user uploads of Excel files. Though the upload seems to succeed according to the user interface, my subsequent checks in the NetSuite File Cabinet reveal that the file size is always zero. I have employed log.debug to verify the file size before uploading, and the logs indicate the size is accurate, leading me to question whether this is an issue with the code or perhaps related to file permissions.

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType Suitelet
 */
define(["N/ui/serverWidget", "N/file"], function (ui, file) {
  function onRequest(context) {
    if (context.request.method === "GET") {
      var form = ui.createForm({ title: "Upload Excel File" });
      var fileField = form.addField({
        id: "custpage_file",
        type: ui.FieldType.FILE,
        label: "Choose an Excel file",
      });
      form.addSubmitButton("Upload");
      context.response.writePage(form);
    } else {
      var uploadedFile = context.request.files.custpage_file;
      log.debug("File Name:", uploadedFile.name);
      log.debug("File Size:", uploadedFile.size);
      

      var fileObj = file.create({
        name: uploadedFile.name,
        fileType: file.Type.EXCEL, // Explicitly set the fileType
        content: uploadedFile.getContents(),
        folder: 5034,
      });
      var fileId = fileObj.save();
      context.response.write("File uploaded successfully with ID: " + fileId);
      log.debug("Uploaded file type:", uploadedFile.fileType);
    }
  }

  return {
    onRequest: onRequest,
  };
});
```

In the file cabinet, I can locate the file, and the file name is correct, but its size is zero. Moreover, when I attempt to open it, the system indicates that the file is corrupted.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is with the file content, the `uploadedFile.getContents()` namely, it doesn't produce what's expected by the file.create() method. What's in it, could you log it? `log.debug("Uploaded file content:", uploadedFile.getContents());`

Comment: also please log the whole file object: `log.debug("Uploaded file:", JSON.stringify(uploadedFile, null, ' '));` May not work, of course, if the size is too big.
If it doesn't work log the `updoadedFile.fileType`, `updoadedFile.isText`, `uploadedFile.encoding`

Comment: Understood. I will verify the encoding of the uploaded data. Thank you for your response.